# How to restrict how many times the same element can be printed from a list?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Working on an assignment question which asks to make a python function which limits repeats of an element to `n` times. For example, given the list:

`[1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,4,4,4,5,5,5,"jim","jim",6,6,"bob","bob","bob"] with n = 2`

The returned list would be:
`[1,1,3,3,2,2,4,4,5,5,"Jim","Jim",6,6,"Bob","Bob"]`

```py
def remove(items, n = 1):
    i = items
    return (list(set(i)))
```

I know that `sets` does not allow duplicates. But I want to control how many times an element can be repeated.

Comment: As you see: set allows exactly one occurrence of an element. If you want more, you need something to count them, like keeping element-counter pairs. And that could be a dict.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is using `itertools.groupby` and `itertools.islice` from Python's standard library:

```
lst = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,"jim","jim",6,6,"bob","bob","bob"]

from itertools import groupby, islice

def remove(items, n=2):
    new_lst = []
    for v, g in groupby(items):
        new_lst.extend(islice(g, 0, n))
    return new_lst

print(remove(lst, 2))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 'jim', 'jim', 6, 6, 'bob', 'bob']
```

---

EDIT:

If you want to remove duplicates too later in the list, you can use `set()` with already seen items:

```
lst = [1,1,2,2,3,3,1,2]

from itertools import groupby, islice

def remove(items, n=2):
    new_lst, seen = [], set()
    for v, g in groupby(items):
        if not v in seen:
            new_lst.extend(islice(g, 0, n))
            seen.add(v)
    return new_lst

print(remove(lst, 2))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Something I'd like to add that I forgot to in the question was how do I make the function go through the whole list and not the number just directly beside it. For example if a list like [1,1,2,2,3,3,1,2] was given and n = 1, [1,2,3,1,2] would be returned which clearly still has duplicates in it. Thank you for the reply though.

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer with `groupby`, but if you want an option without itertools, you can make a simple generator that keeps track of the count and only yields results within the limit. Something like:

```
l = [1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,4,4,4,5,5,5,"jim","jim",6,6,"bob","bob","bob"]
n = 2

def removedupes(l, n):
    count = 0
    prev = None
    for c in l:
        if c == prev:
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 0
        if count < n:
            yield c
        prev = c

list(removedupes(l, n))
# [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 'jim', 'jim', 6, 6, 'bob', 'bob', 9, 9]
```

Comment: Something I'd like to add that I forgot to in the question was how do I make the function go through the whole list and not the number just directly beside it. For example if a list like [1,1,2,2,3,3,1,2] was given and n = 1, [1,2,3,1,2] would be returned which clearly still has duplicates in it. Thank you for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the comment: one could build a statistics of elements which have been encountered already, and append an element to the filtered list only if it has less-than-n occurrences so far:

```
def remove(items, n = 1):
  stats={}
  filtered=[]
  for item in items:
    if item not in stats:
      stats[item]=0
    if stats[item]<n:
      filtered.append(item)
    stats[item]+=1
  return filtered

orig=[1,2,1,1,3,2,3,3,2,4,4,4,5,5,5,"jim",6,"jim",6,"bob",6,"bob","bob","bob"]
print(remove(orig))
print(remove(orig,2))
```

will produce

> ```
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'jim', 6, 'bob']
> [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 'jim', 6, 'jim', 6, 'bob', 'bob']
> ```

Then you can do the crazy stuff if you want, like replacing the loop with `functools.reduce()` and using Python's ternary expression:

```
import functools
def fun(acc,item):
  acc[1][item]=1 if item not in acc[1] else acc[1][item]+1
  if acc[1][item]<=acc[2]:
    acc[0].append(item)
  return acc
remove=lambda items,n=1:functools.reduce(fun,items,([],{},n))[0]
```

then just rewrite `fun()` into another `lambda`:

```
fun=lambda acc,item:(
      acc[1].update({item:1 if item not in acc[1] else acc[1][item]+1}),
      acc[0].append(item) if acc[1][item]<=acc[2] else None,
      acc
    )[2]
```

and wrap the entire thing into a single line:

```
remove=lambda items,n=1:functools.reduce(
         lambda acc,item:(
           acc[1].update({item:1 if item not in acc[1] else acc[1][item]+1}),
           acc[0].append(item) if acc[1][item]<=acc[2] else None,
           acc
         )[2],
       items,([],{},n))[0]
```

Then you can present it to your enemies (it actually works: https://ideone.com/Q1YvkG)
Of course in practice stick with the first one, perhaps with the ternary if you really want to.